# What '~5' means in 'flutter test' output?

Tags: flutter-test

In the output of `flutter test` I see `05:46 +869 ~12 -8: Some tests failed.`

This means 869 tests passed, 8 tests failed, but what does `~12` mean?

Answer (score 0):

`~5` means 5 tests were skipped per configuration.